# Registering a device as a Thing to AWS IoT and linking it with a user account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, alexa-skills-kit

We are going to develop a WiFi LED that can be controlled by an Alexa Skill. We plan to use the AWS IoT platform for this, but there are some things that we find quite hard to understand.

Our first step would be to create an Alexa Skill that could turn the LED on/off. So, we first added an AWS Lambda function for that, and set Alexa Skill as the trigger of the function. But we haven't really start to code for the function part yet. Just did some "Hello World" testing.

Next we were ask to register a "Thing" in AWS IoT platform. So, we registered a "Thing" called WiFiLightBulb. After that we tested the "Thing" we just registered by downloading test package generated from the AWS IoT platform and executed it on our computer. The connection seems to be working because we can see that the messages keep popping out in the terminal. So now, our current test device (which is our computer, pretending to be the WiFi LED) is now connected to our "Thing" (WiFiLightBulb) in the AWS IoT Platform.

Based on what we researched, we would be able to control it by sending commands to it through the REST Api endpoint URL provided under the "Thing". It looks something like this:

```
a2n7fouzuqbojc.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

So, by looking at this we guess we could do the control in the coding of the Lambda function that we just created earlier.

However, there is one things that we really don't understand until now.

If that "Thing" we just created only allows one device to connect to it, then how will our clients that bought our product connect their device to the AWS IoT platform? Plus, we created that "Thing" under our developer account. We thought that if there are thousands of our devices out there, then there would be thousands of our "Things". But, no matter what, it's still under our account.

So, does it mean that if a user wants to use our device, he would need to register his device, as a "Thing" in **HIS** Amazon account? if so, how can we provide a function for registering that device? We don't see any documentation about that.

And what if the user has multiple units of our device, how can we link those device under his Amazon account?

We've been reading a lot in the documentation, but weren't able to find any solution to our problem.

Comment: I think you are looking for a program which can create a thing dynamically in amazon IOT console,

Here is the amazon sdk available to create a thing, policy and certificate dynamically. https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot.html#client (This is a python sdk doc, see for others...)

If you are selling 100 devices then you have to create 100 thing in amazon registry, once you have created the thing then you have to download the certificate files for each device and upload it to your device,
So that each device will be able to communicate with the IOT message broker.

Comment: @Vineesh Hi, thanks for the link. If each of the device created a thing in the amazon registry. Does it mean that device can be used by anyone? I mean there's no ownership or linking between an amazon user and a thing?

Comment: You can make the thing accessible to each customer by making a AWS IOT policies. That means you can create a policy for customer A which can associate with all the things of customer A, which customer B cannot access. Device communicate with the thing in aws using publish and subscribe. You can create a ploicy that allows customer A to communicate to only his devices. Hope this link will help you,  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorization.html

Comment: @Vineesh thank you so much for the help. That helped me understand a bit  more about AWS IoT. Now, what really confused me is that, why are we registering things manually under the AWS IoT account when we can just do it by code from the device point. Are we doing that only for development and debugging purpose?

Comment: You can create the thing either manually or by using code. If you have more number of device it is not advisable to add device manually. either way you have to download the certificate and add the certificate to your device.

Comment: @Vineesh Thank you for your patience in answering my question. OK, so if my device registered itself as a thing in the Amazon registry. Will I get a graphical view of the thing shadow? Because when I create a thing manually, I can see the state of the thing shadow in my developer account. So, if the device just created itself then connected itself to AWS IoT, then how will I be able to know under which account it is registered? and where can I see the state of the things shadow?

Comment: I hope this video will answer most of your questions, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iwwBXFBAcU

Comment: @Vineesh Thank you so much!

Comment: @finalstatic Were you able to figure out this issue? I am also trying to understand how to self register IoT devices.

Comment: @DanielKaparunakis Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @finalstatic can I email you and ask a few questions?

Comment: @DanielKaparunakis If you're going to ask about AWS IoT, I am afraid I could not help you, because I left this and went on with other solutions.

Comment: @finalstatic I have a very similar use case to yours so I would love to hear what solutions you found, even if they don't involve AWS IoT.